# What is the EVD operation that replaces Cholesky decomposition in lme4qtl R package?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, cholesky-decomposition

I am working with ***pedigreemm*** and ***lme4qtl*** R packages.
If I understand it correctly, both are extensions of the ***lme4*** package, which doesn't allow for correlation between random effect clusters, and so both aforementioned packages use the *Cholesky decomposition* to solve this issue.

However, *Cholesky decomposition* requires full rank of the random effect covariance matrix (G). In case this is not satisfied, ***lme4qtl*** replaces the *Cholesky decomposition* by the *EVD (eigenvalue decomposition) operation*.

My question is, what exactly does EDC do? Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find details about the method anywhere.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I asked the same question on the lme4qtl github page and got a very useful answer with examples: https://github.com/variani/lme4qtl/issues/22